# Most pythonic way to refactor multiple equality checks

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring, zen-of-python

Given an if statement like:

```
if response.status == SUCCESS or \
   response.status == FAILURE or \
   response.status == CLEAR or \
   response.status == READY:
```

Is it better to refactor like (1):

```
if any(response.status == status for status in (SUCCESS, FAILURE, CLEAR, READY):
```

Or (2):

```
if response.status in {SUCCESS, FAILURE, CLEAR, READY}:
```

My hunch is that 1 is better as it is more transparent (if not also more readable), but 2 is more concise and avoids having to iterate through each item in the tuple.

Comment: I would use last method because it is more readable.

Answer (score -1):

You could use tuple or list like this, no need to iterate. (Python3.7)

```
>>>'SUCCESS' in ('SUCCESS', 'FAILURE', 'CLEAR', 'READY')
True
```

your case

```
if response.status in (SUCCESS, FAILURE, CLEAR, READY):
```

Comment: Not sure why got -1? 
At least leave the reason when you do it.

Comment: How is this supposed to be an answer? You ignore what they ask and instead offer yet another alternative and it's almost identical to their second alternative and you don't say anything about that (like, why yours might be any better).

Comment: This is alternative to option 1, and it is pythonic way of doing it. 
When you have example provided then explanation is not required always.